# OpenCV video transparency too slow, video lagging, can i speed it up?

Tags: python, opencv, graphics, video-processing

Using OpenCv and python I'm taking two videos and showing them at the same time on top of each other, semi-transparent.

My issue is that the videos are playing back too slow. The videos are lagging.

Is the code that is calculating the transparency the point that is making the code too slow?

What can I do to speed it up?

Code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

video = cv.VideoCapture('photos/1.mp4')
video2 = cv.VideoCapture('photos/2.mp4')


while True:

    ret, frame = video.read()
    ret2, frame2 = video2.read()

    # loop videos
    if not ret:
        print('no video')
        video.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
        continue
    if not ret2:
        print('no video')
        video2.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
        continue


    # Blend the two images and show the result
    tr = 0.5  # transparency between 0-1, show camera if 0
    frame_trans = ((1 - tr) * frame.astype(float) + tr * frame2.astype(float)).astype(np.uint8)
    cv.imshow('Transparent result', frame_trans)


    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('d'):
        break

video.release()
video2.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: how about you use GPU-accelerated graphics, i.e. OpenGL or others?

Comment: Comment out the line that mixes the videos and then just display the first video instead of the mixed one. If it no longer lags, it was the mixing that was slowing you down. If it still lags, it's the reading of the two streams.

Comment: You could try storing the videos on a RAMdrive to see if that helps.

Comment: You can replace your blending code with OpenCV's built-in, optimised `cv.addWeighted()` function to improve performance.

Comment: You've gone very quiet. How are you getting on with this?

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help and sorry for the silence, my children came home with stomach flu and completly destroyed us.

I will read up on cv.addWeighted()! Thanks.

I have tried to understand how to store the videos in RAM but have comprehened, can you point me in a direction?

Would switching to C++ or java make a huge difference in this case?